# PHP ansi to utf8 and vice versa

Tags: php, utf-8

I just want to accomplish something where I want to convert strings from ansi to utf8 and vice versa.

example: to_ansi(1234)
expected result: NLKJ

example: to_utf8(NLKJ)
expected result: 1234

```
functions I currently have are:

function to_ansi($str)
{
    $newString = "";
    $reversedString = strrev($str);
    for($i=0; $i < strlen($reversedString); $i++ ) {
        $newString .= iconv(mb_detect_encoding(), 'UTF-8', chr(ord($reversedString[$i]) * 1.5));
    }
    return $newString;
}

function to_utf8($str)
{
    $newString = "";
    $reversedString = strrev($str);
    for($i=0; $i < strlen($reversedString); $i++ ) {
        $newString .= iconv(mb_detect_encoding(), 'UTF-8', chr(ord($reversedString[$i]) / 1.5));
    }
    return $newString;
}
```

usnig those functions above I get

example: to_ansi(1234)
result: NLKI

example: to_utf8(NLKJ)
result: 1224

actually I'm just interpreting vbs to PHP and the original functions are:

```
Function ToAnsi(ByVal strPassword As String) As String
Dim strLetter As String
Dim strRevPass As String
Dim strNewPass As String

strRevPass = strReverse(strPassword)
strNewPass = ""

For a = 1 To Len(strRevPass)

    strLetter = Mid$(strRevPass, a, 1)
    strNewPass = strNewPass & Chr((Asc(strLetter) * 1.5))

Next a

Text2.Text = strNewPass
End Function



Function ToUTF8(ByVal strPassword As String)
Dim strLetter As String
Dim strRevPass As String
Dim strNewPass As String

strRevPass = strReverse(strPassword)
strNewPass = ""

For a = 1 To Len(strRevPass)

    strLetter = Mid$(strRevPass, a, 1)
    strNewPass = strNewPass & Chr(Asc(strLetter) / 1.5)

Next a

txtText3.Text = strNewPass

End Function
```

Comment: Why do you think that 1234 in ANSI should NLKJ in UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that 1234 in ANSI should NLKJ in UTF-8?

The reason of your problem might be a rounding error. You're multiplying and dividing by 1.5. For instance the letter 'y' (ASCII 122) divided by 1.5 is 80 2/3, which is treated as 81 (there are no fractions in character codes). Then back: 81 * 1.5 = 121.5 which is treated as 122, resulting in a 'z'.

So it's hard to grasp what the meaning of this code is. It certainly isn't a regular ANSI to UTF-8 conversion.

It seems to do some password hashing/encoding, but in a way that is very insecure. It's just a very simple encoding algorithm that can be very easily decoded as well, apart from the fact that it is inherently broken, and mangles your data beyond repair.

Comment: I am able to convert normal string into ascii... my only problem is how to convert ascii to normal string

Comment: Where is ascii in you question? And what is a 'normal' string to your definition?

Comment: I think you need to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)